# No localizo mi base de datos sqlite en mi dispositivo físico android

Tags: android

Estoy  corriendo mi  aplicación android studio sobre un dispositivo físico, pero  no logro localizar la base  de datos.
Mi  dispositivo  no está rooteado, me  encontré  este  código en  internet la cuál  no logro implementarlo.
Les agradezco que me  den ideas.

```
 public static void BD_backup() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    final String inFileName ="/data/data/com.example.usuarioadministrador.miproyecto/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME;
    File dbFile= new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    fis=new FileInputStream(dbFile);
    String directorio = obtenerDirectorioCopias();
    File d = new File(directorio);
    if (!d.exists()) {
        d.mkdir();
    }
    String outFileName=directorio + "/" + DATABASE_NAME +""+timeStamp;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si conoces el nombre de la base de datos, regularmente creada en la clase que extiende `SQLiteOpenHelper` puedes obtener la ruta mediante el método **[getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String))**.

> [getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) Devuelve la ruta absoluta en el sistema de archivos donde se almacena
>   una base de datos creada con openOrCreateDatabase (String, int,
>   SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory).

Ejemplo:

```
String pathDatabase = getDatabasePath("mybasededatos.db").getAbsolutePath();
```

obtendrías algo similar a :

```
/data/user/0/<nombre de paquete>/databases/mybasededatos.db
```

**Para acceder a la ruta y obtener la base de datos es necesario tener permisos de root**, si requieres tener estos permisos en tu dispositivo es bajo tu propio riesgo. Te recomiendo en cambio copiar la base de datos a el almacenamiento externo para que la puedas analizar.

---

Si estas en una clase que no es `Activity` necesitas el contexto para acceder al método :

```
  String pathDatabase = getActivity().getDatabasePath("mybasededatos.db").getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada te digo que no puedes acceder a ésta carpeta (data sin ser root).

Segundo la respuesta a tu pregunta está aqui:

```html
 final String inFileName ="/data/data/com.example.usuarioadministrador.miproyecto/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME;
```

Que te dice que está en la carpeta data/data/com.example.usuarioadministrador.miproyecto/databases/ Asi que te recomiendo rootear tu celular y listo.

Pd: puedes probar con ESfile. Creo que podras entrar a data sin ser root.
Saludos