# ¿Cómo acceder a la Base de Datos SQLite creada en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, android-sqlite

He estado investigando al parecer queda en una carpeta del Android Device Monitor llamada data, pero el problema es que no puedo acceder a esa carpeta, me aparece el simbolo para desplegar pero al darle click no me desplega nada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hace varias versiones de Android Studio esto ya no es posible, **la única manera es tener [permisos Root](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45987/no-localizo-mi-base-de-datos-sqlite-en-mi-dispositivo-f%C3%ADsico-android/45996#45996) en tu dispositivo** para que puedas acceder a ese directorio.

Una opción es realizar una copia de tu Base de datos en el almacenamiento externo o SDCard:

[Hacer una copia se seguridad de una base de datos a la tarjeta sd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82080/hacer-una-copia-se-seguridad-de-una-base-de-datos-a-la-tarjeta-sd/86857#86857)

puedes usar el siguiente método:

```
public static boolean copiaBD(String from, String to) {
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        File dir = new File(to.substring(0, to.lastIndexOf('/')));
        dir.mkdirs();
        File tof = new File(dir, to.substring(to.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        int byteread;
        File oldfile = new File(from);
        if(oldfile.exists()){
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(tof);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();
        }
        result = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("copyFile", "Error copiando archivo: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

primeramente obtenemos el path donde se encuentra la base de datos:

```
 String pathDB = getDatabasePath(NOMBRE_DATABASE).toString();
```

con este path, indicas destino de archivo a copiar:

```
copiaBD(pathDB,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/" + <nombre archivo destino>);
```

No olvidar agregar el permiso para poder escribir en el almacenamiento externo:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

Ahora, de esta forma podras acceder a tu base de datos sin problema mediante el `File Explorer` del Android Device Monitor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Un placer, saludos!