# Hacer una copia se seguridad de una base de datos a la tarjeta sd

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo esta base de datos simple y quiero realizar un backup a la tarjeta sd, como lo puedo hacer?

```
public class Usuario extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sql ="CREATE TABLE Cliente (id INTEGER, nombre TEXT, apellido TEXT)";

    public Usuario(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST Cliente");
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No existe un método dentro de la clase `SQLiteOpenHelper` para realizar un respaldo, para esto necesitas realizar una copia de la base de datos y agregarla a tu sdcard, puedes usar este método,

```
public static boolean copiaBD(String from, String to) {
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        File dir = new File(to.substring(0, to.lastIndexOf('/')));
        dir.mkdirs();
        File tof = new File(dir, to.substring(to.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        int byteread;
        File oldfile = new File(from);
        if(oldfile.exists()){
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(tof);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();
        }
        result = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("copyFile", "Error copiando archivo: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

primeramente obtenemos el path donde se encuentra la base de datos:

```
 String pathDB = getDatabasePath(NOMBRE_DATABASE).toString();
```

con este path, indicas destino de archivo a copiar:

```
copiaBD(pathDB,
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/" + <nombre archivo destino>);
```

---

No olvidar agregar el permiso para poder escribir en el almacenamiento externo:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Si el sistema operativo es Android 6.0 o posterior, tienes que requerir permisos manualmente.

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en un AlertDialog en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

Answer (score 0):

La base de datos sqlite es simplemente un fichero. Puedes copiar el fichero a la sdcard sin más. Te copio y pego un fragmento de código para realizarlo:

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
                String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Recuerda dar permisos de escritura:

Enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093458/copy-database-file-to-sdcard-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Saludos