# No puedo acceder a la carpeta data de mi app desde el Android Device Monitor

Tags: android

Necesito acceder a la carpeta "data" desde el Android Device Monitor, pero no me permite abrirla porque no tengo permisos. He abierto el programa como administrador y he cambiado la API de android por la 22 pero sigue sin dejarme abrir la carpeta "data". La cuestión es que he creado una base de datos SQlite y necesito copiar el documento DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un movil en condiciones normales, la carpeta data solo es accesible en modo root, lo cual implica "rootear el equipo" siendo diferente para cada equipo el procedimiento para hacerlo, ademas de no ser un procedimiento aceptado por los fabricantes(Si rootea el equipo es bajo su cuenta y riesgo) Pese a ello, Android proporciona un Api completo para manipular la base de datos, pero se maneja a nivel de programacion. Lo anterior para responder a la pregunta que esta titulada, respecto a lo de copiar la base de datos es posible hacerlo, ya fue respondido en este link

[Hacer una copia se seguridad de una base de datos a la tarjeta sd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82080/hacer-una-copia-se-seguridad-de-una-base-de-datos-a-la-tarjeta-sd/86857?s=4|0.1305#86857)