# Problema con permisos al navegar por archivos de dispositivo en el cmd con ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite3

soy un desarrollador principiante y tengo un problemilla. Estoy usando la base de datos SQLite3 y para poder ver y administrar la base de datos a traves del cmd he intentado acceder al device con el *adb -e shell*. Esto funciona y se que se mete en el device emulado porque al cerrar el emulador se sale en el terminal también a la carpeta plataform-tools. La cuestion es que una vez dentro puedo avanzar *cd data* y *cd data* pero a partir de ahi ya me dice *Permission denied*. 
Me extraña todo esto porque en otro ordenador yo ya lo hice y en ningun momento me puso que no tenia permisos.

A continuación pondre los comandos que he introducido hasta llegar ahi tapando algunos datos personales con *:

cd *[hubicacion Sdk]*

cd platform-tools

adb -e shell

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi como veis me dice ya que no tengo permisos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como conceder los permisos necesarios para poder navegar por los archivos.

Espero que me haya explicado bien o que al menos me hayais conseguido entender. 
A ver si podeis ayudarme con el problema.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Estas obteniendo el error `Permission denied` ya que en realidad tratas de acceder al directorio de almacenamiento interno (`/data/data` )del dispositivo, pero esto no es posible, **Actualmente por seguridad, la única manera es tener permisos `Root` en tu dispositivo para que puedas acceder a ese directorio.**

Revisa la informacion de esta pregunta

[¿Cómo acceder a la Base de Datos SQLite creada en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73795/c%c3%b3mo-acceder-a-la-base-de-datos-sqlite-creada-en-android-studio)

Si deseas acceder a la informacion de la base de datos considera realizar una copia del almacenamiento interno al externo

[¿Como copiar una base de datos Sqlite o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno/79011#79011)