# Intento hacer que mi app importe y exporte la db de sqlite es para todo los dias hacer copia y subirlo a la misma app pero a otro dispositivo movil

Tags: android, android-studio

Intenté hacerlo con algo de aquí del foro, pero no me sale bien y no entiendo una parte, quiero que la db quede guardada en descargas del teléfono, para así yo poderla enviar a otro teléfono

Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.

```
String pathDB = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NOMBRE).toString();
```

Copia base de datos a destino definido.

```
copyFile( pathDB, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/" + <nombre archivo destino> );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si deseas copiar directamente la bd a otro dispositivo, es un poco amplia tu pregunta

Comment: tengo dos dispositivos con la misma app, quiero descargar una copia de la bd del dispositivo 1, y luego subirla dentro dispositivo 2 que me reemplace toda la db que tiene.

Comment: Para copiar la base de datos, ya existe una respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73795/c%c3%b3mo-acceder-a-la-base-de-datos-sqlite-creada-en-android-studio